# issue with same named Provisioning Profile with different account and bundle ids

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios8.3

I am facing an issue with Provisioning profile with the same name, i have two Provisioning profile two certificates with different Bundle Identifiers. But the issue is that two provisioning profiles has same name like `ABCDMobile` and `ABCDMobile` at the time of selecting an Provisioning profile it shows only one Provisioning profile and at the time of selecting a certificate it also shows only one distribution certificate.

If any one face these kind of issue help me, is there any possible way for this.

Can i able to change the Provisioning profile name ?

Answer (score 1):

--> Due to same name of provisioning profile it will replace one by another provisioning profile so last installed provisioning profile will appear and it's related certificate also.

-->Go to : developer.apple.com > Member Center > Login with developer account > Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Profiles All > Select your profile and edit the name and everything you can edit for the profile from here.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you. I dont have access to that developer account. i'm doing in another way.

Comment: @Balu there is no another way to change the provisioning profile name. You must need access to change the name. Or you can just try directly change the name. I never used this trick but just try once may be solve your problem.

Comment: @Kukadiya That trick didn't work i already tried. Any way my issue was resolved as of now. I'll request then for account acess. Thanq for ur quick response.